# How to easily insert frames at the end of a video?

Tags: video, editing

I need to insert a still image for several seconds at the end of my 1080p video. I can't find how to do that with Virtual Dub. Tried with Microsoft Movie Maker but it messes the resolution, changes the format, etc. Any quick solution I haven't thought about ?

Answer (score 1):

A quick Google search for the terms `add photo with virtual dub` shows [this](http://www.videoforums.co.uk/general-software-problems/20438-insert-image-video.html) result. Quoting:

> - save the titlescreen in bitmap (same size of video, obviously)
> - import image in VirtualDub (with Open command)
> - select the single frame you get after opening and copy it
> - open your video
> - paste the frame you copied in the desired position (every ctrl-v is a single frame, if your movie is 25fps, just paste 25 times to create
>     1-second title sequence)

For your case you don't have a titlescreen but just a regular image.

You can select frames in VirtualDub as following:

- Click on the timeline on the location where your frame that you want to select. In the image below I clicked on frame 30.
- Click on the button where the arrow points to. This sets your beginning of the selection.

[image]

- If you want to select one frame, click on the 31st frame (as in the image below) and click the button that is indicated by the arrow. This sets your endpoint of the selection.

[image]

You can also select a series of frames this way.

Comment: Thanks, but how do you select a frame (any frame) in Virtual Dub ? To my knowledge it's impossible.

Comment: I've added some clarification to my answer. I hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for that, I can now select my frame. However I still can't follow the instructions you pasted initially, which state that the frame must be copied then pasted at the end of the video. Problem is, I don't see how to copy the frame I selected. Edit > Copy after frame has been selected then Edit > Paste doesn't do anything. Seems like nothing is copied. How can I copy it ?

Comment: Virtualdub is ancient and buggy.  On my VirtualDub 1.10.4, I must select do Edit-Copy, then go to where I want the frame, then Edit-Paste, then Edit-Undo, then go to that place again, then Edit-Paste.  Then you have to go back and forward a few times to see the frame appear.  Also, make sure you delay about 1 second between each operation.  It seems to happen "in the background" and doing anything while it is pasting causes odd behavior.